# angularjs scope.$eval unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If i have a property with a dash, lets say `a-a` with the value of `'some value'` on my scope, and i try to evaluate

```
scope.$eval('a-a')
```

it will return `0`. I suppose it thinks that the hyphen is a subtraction operator, but anyhow: is there a way to call `$eval` that will return what i need (i.e. `'some-value'`)?

This fiddle shows the example:http://jsfiddle.net/BusD7/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with what you are trying to do here.

In your fiddle, you have

```
$scope['a-a'] = 'some value';
```

The first issue is that 'a-a' is NOT a correct variable name.
JS variables can have underscores(_), alpha-numeric(a-z,1-9), and dollar-signs($)
You are trying to create a variable with a hyphen(-); this is not allowed in JS.

See this doc.
[JS variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals)

Secondly, in your jsFiddle you have

```
{{$eval('a-a')}}
```

The Angularjs $eval function is trying to make sense of the EXPRESSION you provided 'a-a', and yes the $eval function is trying to evaluate the - operator.

See here for an example:

[Angularjs Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

That is what Angular is doing when you just do this

```
{{ a-a }} which will result in 0 as well.

and {{ 'a-a' }} would just result in a string of a-a
```

Play around on your jsFiddle and you will see what it does.

To answer your question, do this to get it to work.

```
 $scope['a-a'] = 'some value';    to this    $scope['a_a'] = 'some value';
```

and

```
{{$eval('a-a')}}        to this      {{$eval('a_a')}}
```

Now that you know variable names cannot have hyphens (in JS), what exactly are you trying to accomplish, and I will assist getting you there.

**UPDATE:**

Yes of course, thank you for the correction. You are creating an object property using bracket notation. I mostly keep to dot notation (even when using bracket notation ), and dot noation only allows normal variable names.

Here is a link to both notation types

> An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square bracket notation.

and link [Bracket Notation Information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

To solve your issue using Angularjs please do the following:

Add your 'a-a' property name to a new object and attach to $scope.

```
like this: $scope.myNewObject = {};
           $scope.myNewObject['a-a'] = 'some value';

Then call it like this:
           {{ myNewObject['a-a'] }}

Will return: some value
```

Here is the idea working in a jsFiddle

[Working Answer Link](http://jsfiddle.net/CriddleCraddle/BusD7/28/)

Comment: While i agree that `The first issue is that 'a-a' is NOT a correct variable name` it IS a correct **property** name. And in that example 'a-a' is not a variable but a property on $scope.